# C++ stringstream conversion to double with operator>>

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to read a column file in C++ by overloading the stream input operator.
This is the main function to read each line in the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector <double> record_t;

istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, record_t& record )
{
  record.clear();

  string line;
  getline( ins, line );

  stringstream ss( line );
  double f;
  while (ss >> f)
    record.push_back(f);

  return ins;
}
```

which works fairly well in most cases.
But for this line

```
55000.003520    -0.009740   0.000721    -0.024600   0.000000
```

the first field is stored as `55000.0` instead of `55000.003520`
Is there any way I can make it read the correct value with all the significant digits?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: how are you *checking* that only 55000.000000 is stored?! because this looks like what ever you use to output the actual value simply rounds to one six significant digits.

Comment: My mistake, if I print the output value with `cout << setprecision(15) << t[0];` it shows `55000.00352`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can also use `std::fixed`

Answer (score 0):

To archive the answer to the problem:

The number is actually read in and stored correctly. The way OP checked was by simply piping it to `cout`, which has a very limited default output precision, so many of the digits were just "rounded away" for printing.